# Is it possible to disable f:event type=“preRenderView” listener on fileupload primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a fileUploader which disappears after partial site refresh

Here is my xhtml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/traleerdf-template.xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView"
                 listener="#{registration.loadRegistrationDetails()}" ></f:event>
    </f:metadata>
    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide();"/>
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Saving"
              draggable="false" closable="false">
    <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </p:dialog>

    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <p:panelGrid  id="detail" columns="1" >
          <p:dataTable var="reg" id="datatable" value="#{registration.registrationDTOs}" rows="12">
             <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:5%">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{reg.sourceName}"/>
             </p:column>
             <p:column headerText="Path Prefix" style="width:5%">
                 <p:outputLabel value="#{reg.pathPrefix}"/>
              </p:column>
              <p:column headerText="Template File" style="width:30%">
                  <p:commandButton id="templateButton" value="Get Template" oncomplete="tempDlg.show();" process="@this" title="Template File"
                    update=":topForm:form:growl :topForm:form:tempId">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{reg}" target="#{registration.registrationDTO}" />
                  </p:commandButton>
               </p:column>
               <p:column style="width:2%" headerText="Update">
                   <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":topForm:form:growl :topForm:form:display"  process="@this" oncomplete="regDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Edit">
                   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{reg}" target="#{registration.registrationDTO}" />
                   </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>
           <p:dialog header="Registration Detail" widgetVar="regDialog" resizable="false" id="regDlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">
               <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" style="margin:0 auto;" >
                  <p:outputLabel id="lblEndpoint" for="txtEndpoint" value="#{msg['Registration.Endpoint']}"/>
                  <h:outputText id="txtEndpoint" value="#{registration.registrationDTO.endpoint}"/>
                   <p:outputLabel id="lblSourceName" for="txtSourceName" value="#{msg['Registration.sourceName']}"/>
                    <p:inputText  required="true"  id="txtSourceName" value="#{registration.registrationDTO.sourceName}" requiredMessage="Source name not entered"/>
                     <p:outputLabel  id="lblPathPrefix" for="txtPathPrefix" value="#{msg['Registration.pathPrefix']}"/>
                     <p:inputText  disabled="true" required="true" id="txtPathPrefix" size="20" value="#{registration.registrationDTO.pathPrefix}" requiredMessage="Path prefix is required"/>
                     <p:outputLabel id="lblTemplateFile" for="txtTemplateFile" value="#{msg['Registration.templateFile']}"/>
                    <p:fileUpload required="true" id="txtTemplateFile" fileUploadListener="#{registration.uploadTemplateFile}"  requiredMessage="Template File required"
                    mode="advanced" widgetVar="txtTemplateFile" value="#{registration.registrationDTO.templateFile}" update=":topForm:form:growl">                                              
                        </p:fileUpload>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" id="btnUpdte" update=":topForm:form:growl :topForm:form:panel" ajax="true" action="#{registration.updateRegistration()}" style="margin-right:20px;"
                                             value="Update" >
                      </p:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
             <p:dialog header="Template Dialog" widgetVar="tempDlg" modal="true" height="100" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
                <p:panelGrid id="tempId" style="margin:0 auto;" columns="2">
                   <p:outputLabel id="TemplateFileLbl" for="TemplateFile" value="#{msg['Registration.templateFile']}"/>
                     <h:outputText value="#{registration.registrationDTO.templateFile}" id="TemplateFile"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
              </p:dialog>
          </p:panelGrid>
       </p:panel>
    </h:form>
   </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
```

The upload button will open a new dialog which allows the user to edit the fields and can upload a new template file.

My Problem is every time the upload button in the dialog is clicked, f:event method method is invoked which is expected as it is of type prerender but is there anyway to avoid this event call for the fileupload because it is overwriting the template file name I uploaded. (prerender method is making a call to db to get the list of details which in the case overriding the template file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the namespaces you're using, I presume you're using JSF 2.2. In this version, you can have

```
<f:viewAction action="#{registration.loadRegistrationDetails()}"/>
```

The `viewAction` tag is not executed on postback by default.